# Show Drop down list below clicked view

Tags: android, android-spinner

[image]

How Do i make this view. I checked Spinner and PopUp window but i failed to do... Please suggest me any examples...

Comment: its actually spinner post your code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should go for Android QuickAction widget.

[image: Vertical Quick Action]

[image]

This is an open source project of GithUb.

https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/NewQuickAction3D

https://github.com/alhneiti/Android-QuickAction

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

I have achived this kind of behavior using a `PopUpWindow`, here is my code:

```
// The method that displays the popup.
private void showStatusPopup(final Activity context, Point p) {

   // Inflate the popup_layout.xml
   LinearLayout viewGroup = (LinearLayout) context.findViewById(R.id.llStatusChangePopup);
   LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.status_popup_layout, null);

   // Creating the PopupWindow
   changeStatusPopUp = new PopupWindow(context);
   changeStatusPopUp.setContentView(layout);
   changeStatusPopUp.setWidth(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
   changeStatusPopUp.setHeight(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
   changeStatusPopUp.setFocusable(true);

   // Some offset to align the popup a bit to the left, and a bit down, relative to button's position.
   int OFFSET_X = -20;
   int OFFSET_Y = 50;

   //Clear the default translucent background
   changeStatusPopUp.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());

   // Displaying the popup at the specified location, + offsets.
   changeStatusPopUp.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, p.x + OFFSET_X, p.y + OFFSET_Y);
}
```

and this is the PopUp layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/devider_popup_task_status_change" 
    android:contentDescription="@drawable/devider_popup_task_status_change"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvInProgress"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/my_black"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="popupStatusChangeOnClick"
    android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:text="@string/inprogress"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/devider_popup_task_status_change" 
    android:contentDescription="@drawable/devider_popup_task_status_change"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvOnTheWay"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/my_black"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="popupStatusChangeOnClick"
    android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:text="@string/ontheway"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/devider_popup_task_status_change" 
    android:contentDescription="@drawable/devider_popup_task_status_change"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvComplete"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/my_black"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="popupStatusChangeOnClick"
    android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:text="@string/complete"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/devider_popup_task_status_change" 
    android:contentDescription="@drawable/devider_popup_task_status_change"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvFailed"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="popupStatusChangeOnClick"
    android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="11dp"
    android:text="@string/failed"
    android:textColor="@color/my_black" />
```

When the `ImageView`'s are only a 1 pixel deviders.

Answer (score 1):

What you ask about is a [Spinner](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html), but you can also make your own popup list, using "[ListPopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListPopupWindow.html)"

Answer (score 0):

you can use spinner also-

```
 String[] branch={"NEW","prev",...};
 ArrayAdapter<String> list;
 spinner=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    list=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,branch);
    spinner.setAdapter(list);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
                        }
```